# python cannot write to file after saved in another editor

Tags: python, file, output

I have a python file which runs continuously, and occasionally takes keyboard input upon which it writes to a file.

However, if I edit the file in another editor (using e.g. sed or head or gedit) and then save it again, my python program no longer writes to the file, even if (when using gedit) I exit out of the editor.

What is the correct way to be able to continue writing to the file?
Here is an example

```
import sys
f = open('tmp.txt', 'ab')
while 1:
   raw_input()
   f.write('this is a test\n')
    f.flush()
f.close()
```

Example:

```
python tmp.py
(enter input) #writes line to file
[ in a separate terminal ] sed -i '$ d' tmp.txt #deletes last line in file
(enter input to python in terminal) #no longer writes to file
```

Comment: Maybe you need to seek to the end before writing. `f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)`

Comment: Maybe you need to be realistic and show that you are not running `sed -i ...` in between `(enter ...` and `(enter ...)` but in a different terminal. Or else you are stopping the script and restarting it.

Comment: Apologies for not making that clear, I was indeed running my file edits in a separate terminal. Peter: that may also have been part of the issue, I will investigate what the ultimate reason is tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OS administrates the read/write access on files. When you first get the writing access to the file outside your loop, you will never get it back inside your loop once it is taken by another process or thread. So setup the file object inside your loop.

```
import sys

while True :
    raw_input()
    with open('tmp.txt', 'ab') as f :
        f.write('this is a test\n')
```

For file objects it is recommended to use a context manager (`with`-Statement). It will automatically open and close the object.

Comment: Wow yes, this is probably the issue, though I will have to go in tomorrow and test it out. Looking back now, I feel a "doh!" -- simplifying it down sure makes it obvious in retrospect (was doing stuff with threads and Tkinter). 
Yesterday I just worked around it by using
`"$ n=4`
`$ tac tmp.txt | sed "1,$n{d}" | tac > out.txt; cat out.txt > tmp.txt"`
which doesn't disturb the file in the same way somehow as my script was able to keep writing to the file (do you know what the difference is?)

Comment: @orangenarwhals: Your command line there is never changing the inode associated with the file name (`> somefile` truncates an existing `somefile` then writes new data, it doesn't *delete* said file, then create a new one). Most editors use a crash safe form of editing, where a new file is written completely, then an atomic rename operation is issued which renames the new file to the old file name (implicitly deleting the old file). But this means the inode number changes after each save operation, which means open file handles from other programs are invalidated).

Comment: The advantage to the "write new file, rename to replace old file" is that if you lose power (or blue screen, or the program just crashes) at any point prior to the rename, your original file data is intact. In no circumstance does the final file hold anything but the *complete* old data or the *complete* new data. If your computer crashed during `cat out.txt > tmp.txt` step or you killed it midway through processing, `tmp.txt` might contain partially written garbage, or nothing at all, and it might not be possible to tell if `out.txt` or `tmp.txt` was the "correct" data.

Comment: @orangenarwhals Feel free to accept my answer, if it works the way you intended it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

while True :
    with open('tmp.txt', 'ab') as f :
        f.write('this is a test\n')
```

Comment: We answered at almost the same moment. I was a little faster ;)... You forgot the `raw_input()`...

Comment: I am not certain why this is downvoted, but thank you both for rescuing me from my late-night "dope"

Comment: the downvote is probably because you didn't include any description. code-only answers are somewhat frowned upon. Without a description, a beginner won't know if the "secret sauce" is that you used `while True` rather than `while 1`, or `with` instead of a normal call to `open`, or moving the `open` inside the loop, or if it's because you removed the call to `flush`. A lot of those will seem obvious to you, but possibly not to someone who needs to ask this question in the first place.